# what the fastest way to get snapshot from ip-cam

Tags: c#, image, video-capture, snapshot

I have an IP-cam that i want to get a snapshot from it when event get fired.

I have tried to get images from it using an option in it's firmware but it's taking much time about 4-11 sec.

I need another way to get a snapshot from it using c# code.
I'm developing app using c# 3.5
OS windows server 2008

Any sample is very welcome and I will try it now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We really need more information to be able to help, particular, what model camera is it? If you can get a video feed, you could in theory extract a frame out of it.

Comment: camera  model Acti camera ACM5611,YES i cant get a video feed.I can get a snapshot from it using this link "http://IP/cgi-bin/cmd/encoder?SNAPSHOT" but it's taking about 4-11 sec...thats why i need to get it faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to look into OpenCV.  There are a couple C# ports available out there:

[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

[opencvdotnet](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/)

[opencvsharp](http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/)